# How to correct column name values in MySQL multiple JOINS query

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, left-join, mysql-5.6

I need to display a product with its price, and current stock (if any) of that product with a specific color and attributes. It does what it should, partially. This is the explanation of the query (or at least what it should be doing):

- Get basic information about the product from `store_product`
- A product has a stock. That stock is connected to a color ID, and an attribute detail ID.
- A product stock that's associated with a color ID can have multiple attribute detail IDs. So for example, a red shirt stock value from poliester material can be different than a red shirt stock value from M size.

For this particular example, i'm trying to receive the stock value for product ID `59` that meet these specific values

- `id_color` must be `1` (1 = *red*, which has a custom name called *red deadpool*)
- `id_detail` must be `4` in one row, and `50` in another row (`4` = *Size M* / `50` = *Material Poliester*)

This is what i'm currently receiving:

[image: current result]

The query is partially correct because:

- I'm getting 2 rows, one for each color/attribute combination
- I'm getting the correct `id_stock` ID for each row, and i'm also getting the correct stock value for the color/attribute combination.

The issue is that, although the stock information is correct, the `id_attribute` / `attribute` / `id_detail` / `detail` information is wrong.

This is what i would **need** to receive (i've marked the correction in bold):

[image: corrected result]

```
SELECT store_product.id_product             AS id_product, 
       store_product.NAME                   AS NAME, 
       store_product.price                  AS price, 
       store_product.flg_stock              AS flg_stock, 
       store_product_stock.id               AS id_stock, 
       store_product_stock.stock            AS stock, 
       Ifnull(store_color.NAME, color.NAME) AS color, 
       color.hex                            AS hex, 
       store_attribute.id_attribute         AS id_attribute, 
       store_attribute.NAME                 AS attribute, 
       store_attribute_detail.id_detail     AS id_detail, 
       store_attribute_detail.NAME          AS detail 
FROM   store_product 
       LEFT JOIN store_product_color 
              ON store_product_color.id_color = store_product_color.id_color 
       LEFT JOIN color 
              ON color.id_color = store_product_color.id_color 
       LEFT JOIN store_color 
              ON store_color.id_color = color.id_color 
                 AND store_color.id_store = 1 
       LEFT JOIN store_product_detail 
              ON store_product_detail.id_product = store_product.id_product 
       LEFT JOIN store_attribute_detail 
              ON store_attribute_detail.id_detail = 
                 store_product_detail.id_detail 
       LEFT JOIN store_attribute 
              ON store_attribute.id_attribute = 
                 store_attribute_detail.id_attribute 
       LEFT JOIN store_product_stock 
              ON store_product_stock.id_product = store_product.id_product 
                 AND store_product_stock.id_color = 1 
                 AND store_product_stock.id_detail IN( 4, 50 ) 
WHERE  store_product.id_store = 1 
       AND store_product.id_product = 59 
       AND store_product_color.id_color = 1 
GROUP  BY store_product_stock.id
```

Here you can find the whole table structure and the current query which has the issue: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed4025/1)

Any ideas on how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is your sample data set really 'minimal'?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh hi, the image is just for example purposes, the sqlfiddle holds the full text formatted version. Regarding the columns, i removed everything not necessary. Since the example uses multiple joins i didn't want to remove them. If i did, the issue would be easy to reproduce.

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid, and will raise an exception in newer MySQL versions, unless in compatibility mode. MySQL version 8 has window functions, perhaps what you want.

Comment: @jarlh the server is using mysql 5.6, can't do much around that.

Comment: whats your intention for the group by, you are using no aggregation

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN store_product_color 
              ON store_product_color.id_color = store_product_color.id_color  has a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned:

> A product has a stock. That stock is connected to a color ID, and an attribute detail ID.

In your query, your product relates directly to your `color_id`  and your `attribute_detail`.
You are relating your attributes directly to your `store_product` , not with your `color/stock` .

This means that your  id_attribute and attribute are only depending on `store_product.id_product`  but not on your `store_product_stock.id`

**EDIT**
First, thanks for the sqlfiddle.
The way to link your stock and details is using `store_attribute_detail.id_detail = store_product_stock.id_detail`

```
FROM   store_product 
       LEFT JOIN store_product_color 
              ON store_product_color.id_color = store_product_color.id_color 
       LEFT JOIN color 
              ON color.id_color = store_product_color.id_color 
       LEFT JOIN store_color 
              ON store_color.id_color = color.id_color 
                 AND store_color.id_store = 1 

       LEFT JOIN store_product_stock 
              ON store_product_stock.id_product = store_product.id_product 
                 AND store_product_stock.id_color = 1 
                 AND store_product_stock.id_detail IN( 4, 50 ) 

       LEFT JOIN store_attribute_detail 
              ON store_attribute_detail.id_detail = 
                 store_product_stock.id_detail 
       LEFT JOIN store_attribute 
              ON store_attribute.id_attribute = 
                 store_attribute_detail.id_attribute 
        LEFT JOIN store_product_detail 
              ON store_product_detail.id_product = store_product.id_product
```

```
+------------+--------------------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------+--------------+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id_product |           NAME           | price | flg_stock | id_stock | stock |    color     |  hex   | id_attribute | attribute | id_detail |  detail   |
+------------+--------------------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------+--------------+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         59 | Camiseta Júbilo de X-men |  55.1 |         1 |      112 |     5 | red deadpool | f44336 |            1 | Size      |         4 | M         |
|         59 | Camiseta Júbilo de X-men |  55.1 |         1 |      118 |    35 | red deadpool | f44336 |            8 | Material  |        50 | Poliester |
+------------+--------------------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------+--------------+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: We know the structure of the tables

Comment: We don't know if store_attribute_detail has a stock_id column, but for the definition it should.

Comment: we know that it doesn't

Comment: @CarlosSR the sqlfiddle lists all the tables and columns in the schema. If you want I can list them in the original post as well?

Comment: My bad, didn't see the fiddle in the comments. Checking it right now

Comment: @CarlosSR thanks! Sorry for the delay, SO didn't notify my that you updated the original answer. This solves the issue, thanks again for the explanation!